# Windows Server As Router // Internal and External

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, dhcp, nat, windows-server-2016

apologies if I've posted this to the wrong forum topic, hopefully a mod can move it over if so :)

I've been having a issue for a while now, and i know this isn't best practise, and its not intended for use, its just something i want to work on for personal development and experience.

So, i have a Server with Windows Server 2016 Deployed, and i have 1 PCI-E Gigabit card, and the on-board LAN.

I would like to know if its possible to use one adaptor as a 'line out' sort of configuration which is connect directly to the Router, and then the second adaptor as a internal network, handing out DHCP etc, which would go to a switch which all clients connect to.

So basically, connections come into the server via adaptor 2, and then pass through the server and exit to the internet on adaptor 1, basically incoming traffic gets redirected to Adaptor 1 to exit through the router to the internet.

I've been looking at this for a while, and does anyone have any ideas on how to configure this, i have installed Remote Access and enabled routing to the interface connected to the router going to the internet, and then when i connect a client to Adaptor 2, it doesn't seem to pick up the server at all (no DHCP, no Ping response).

I believe it is something to do with the Ipv4 configuration, and i'm just not sure what to set the addresses at, so adaptor 1 can reach the server.

I'm open to all ideas, and suggestions as i'm just about to give up, and i'm not sure whether it is possible but i wouldn't see why it isn't.

Cheers.
(Here is a photo, as i suck sometimes at explaining things)
[Diagram][1]

*UPDATE*
So, i've been reading, and got the server correctly passing traffic as i can see from tracert, it goes from QVCMS1 (server) to BTBUSINESSHUB (router) and then exits the LAN network.
I changed the LAN 1 adapter and router to a subnet of 255.255.255.0, set the IP of 192.168.1.253, and then set the default gateway at 192.168.1.254, DNS as loopback
Then on the second adapter, i set the address to 192.168.150.253, subnet of 255.255.0.0, and default gateway blank, DNS as loopback also.

Adter pointing the DHCP records, Router to: 192.168.150.253, and DNS as 192.168.1.253 (which im sure is not correct causing the issues)

It DID work, but after a ipconfig /renew it timed out and the server was unreachable from the 255.255.255.0 subnet, and the 255.255.0.0 subnet. Restarted and now its back.

FIXED: i've managed to sort it i believe, it wasn't any addressing issue with the subnet mask as you said, i forgot to change the DNS Server record on DHCP, so it was pointing to 192.168.1.253 instead of 192.168.150.253. Also, i made sure i unchecked in DHCP and DNS listening on the adapter that goes to the router, All seems to work now, ill add the screenshots in the first message and tell me what you think, if you have any sugestions as ill probably run into issues later lol. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B112jXDDvFE3Tk5ubmoxRzEzekE

Comment: It will be a great trip to have Windows do this.. something like walking from Rome to Beijing. Good luck! ;)

Comment: All configured, just had to think :)

Answer (score 1):

Your LAN2 `192.168.150.0/16` is actually `192.168.0.0/16`, already including LAN1 `192.168.1.0/24`. (Educate yourself about *Classless Inter-domain Routing* CIDR, read [RFC 4632, 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632#section-3.1).) Therefore,

- your client computers on LAN2 can't understand they would need routing to `192.168.1.0/24` as it already is a part of their own subnet; they try to connect there on *data link layer* (L2).
- your server has two overlapping networks with different subnet masks. That causes it to lose connectivity to both, and the error in your configuration apparantly gets fixed during reboot.

Use a smaller subnet for LAN2: you probably don't need the 65,536 addresses provided by `/16`, anyway. If you need more than the 256 from `192.168.150/24`, you could use `192.168.148/22` with 1024 addresses `192.168.148.0 - 192.168.151.255`, that wouldn't overlap with `192.168.1.0/24`.

Otherwise, it is perfectly possible to use Windows Server 2016 as a router between your two internal networks with server role *Remote Access* > *Routing*, choosing *LAN routing* from the wizard.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i've managed to sort it i believe, it wasn't any addressing issue with the subnet mask as you said, i forgot to change the DNS Server record on DHCP, so it was pointing to 192.168.1.253 instead of 192.168.150.253. Also, i made sure i unchecked in DHCP and DNS listening on the adapter that goes to the router, All seems to work now, ill add the screenshots in the first message and tell me what you think, if you have any sugestions as ill probably run into issues later lol.

Comment: The answer is based on the information provided. The main problem with using Windows Server as a router is that every update etc. will cause downtime to internet connectivity, while routers usually reboots pretty fast and needs less frequent patching.

Comment: Yes, thats true, like i said, its just something i wanted to achieve, and mess around with, its probably not configured very well, but its something to improve on. It opens more doors for me to be able to now setup a server as a router and use TMG, and other features. Ill be testing it for a while to see how it performs, but its not in development and if i was to put it in development, i'd ensure failover was in place, but its just a little household thing ive wanted to do, thanks for the help, ill probably be back soon lol, hope not, cheers!